# How can i make L shaped connected squares?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have got a project while I'm doing it I came across a problem with connecting squares. I should make L shaped squares and fit them on a 12x12 grid. I have tried to do it with coordinates system but its not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should add your code to the question and clarify what exactly is not working (describe your supposed and actual result).

Answer (score 0):

1. Just make to elements under one an other.
2. add the desired width and height with css.

```css
#first {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```